# Ajax request with web method

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Can someone explain me why this gives me an error?

My ajax call something like this.

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btn1').click(function () {
                var values = JSON.stringify({ data: $('#form1').serializeArray() });
                alert($('#form1').serializeArray());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/Test",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    scripts: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: values,
                    success: function (data) { $('#results').append(data.d); },

                    error: function () { $('#results').append('hata'); }
                });
            });        });

            </script>





</head>
<body>


     <form runat="server" id="form1">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">

        <button id="btn1" type="button">bummm</button>
                     <div id="results"></div>

       </form>
</body>
</html>





[WebMethod]

    public static string Test (string data)
        {

        return "İşlem başarılı"+data;
        }
```

It says me  {"Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error: function () { alert('error'); } this return me

Comment: i know, but what is the message you receive when you run the code?
try changing you error method `error: function (err) { alert('error'); }` and debug and inpect the `err` var.

Comment: one error: 500 (Internal Server Error)  and one notification like this:event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: {"Message":"\u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 türü, dizinin serisini kaldırmak için desteklenmez.","StackTrace":"   konum: S

Comment: "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because you wrong call your webmethod with ajax.
Your webmethod have one parameter named `data` with type `string`, but you try send without name, so try change your code like this:

```
var KaydetDataWithAjax = function (e)
 {
        var values =JSON.stringify({data: $(e).serializeArray()});

        alert(values);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Harita.aspx/HaritaKaydet",
            scripts: true,
            data:values,
            success: function (dt) { alert(dt);},
            complete:function(){},
            error: function () { alert('error'); }
        });
  };
```

**UPDATE**

this method work on new project

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Harita.aspx/HaritaKaydet",
        scripts: true,
        data:JSON.stringify({data: 'text'}),
        success: function (dt) { alert(dt);},
        complete:function(){},
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
```

if in your case it not work then possibly helps if you provide little more code

**UPDATE 2**
turns out it's all simple than i thought!
`serializeArray()` returns Array! So it find on server method with parameters something like `List<object>`, so to solve you must stringify array too
so try this code

```
var KaydetDataWithAjax = function (e)
{
    var values =JSON.stringify({data: JSON.stringify($(e).serializeArray())});

    alert(values);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Harita.aspx/HaritaKaydet",
        scripts: true,
        data:values,
        success: function (dt) { alert(dt);},
        complete:function(){},
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
};
```

Comment: try `data:JSON.stringify({data:'test'})`

Comment: I ma getting 'text' value now

Comment: but when I use this.data: $(e).serializeArray() it says me Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: can you provide how you call `KaydetDataWithAjax`?

Comment: take a look at my simple  test case

Comment: It adds also {"d":"İşlem başarılı[{\"name\":\"__VIEWSTATE\",\"value\":\"p4sLRl915UmoG9cz/w76nv/anQVEm3RER7g3Yu, view state how can I ged rid of this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42151/discussion-between-grundy-and-user2460637)